# Spark DataFrame / Dataset groupBy optimization via bucketBy

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, query-optimization, parquet, bucket

I'm researching options for a use-case where we store the dataset as parquet files and want to run efficient groupBy queries for a specific key later on when we read the data.

I've read a bit about the optimizations for groupBy, however couldn't really find much about it (other than RDD level reduceByKey). 
What I have in mind is, if the dataset is written bucketed by the key that will also be used in the groupBy. Theoretically the groupBy could be optimized, since all the rows containing the key will be co-located (and even consecutive if it's also stored sorted on the same key).

One idea i have in mind is to apply the transformation via mapPartitions then groupBy, however, this will require breaking down my functions into two, it's not really desirable. I believe for some class of functions (say sum/count) spark would optimize the query with a similar fashion as well, but the optimization would be kicked in by the choice of function, and would work regardless of the co-location of the rows, but not because of the co-location.

Can spark leverage the co-location of the rows to optimize the groupBy using any function subsequently?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like bucketing's main use-case is for doing JOINs on the bucketed key, which allows Spark to avoid doing a shuffle across the whole table. If Spark knows that the rows are already partitioned across the buckets, I don't see why it wouldn't know to use the pre-partitioned buckets in a GROUP BY. You might need to sort by the group by key as well though.

I'm also interested in this use-case so will be trying it out and seeing if a shuffle occurs.